# Django charset and encoding

Tags: mysql, django, encoding, tinymce

I am trying to store and view greek characters from/to a Mysql db.

I want to use utf8 encoding i alter my db with the following command:

```
ALTER DATABASE el CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

Now when i am trying to create an article i see the following error:

[image: error page]

When i am trying to fetch the article from my db i see something like:

```
mysql> select * from article_article
    -> ;
+----+------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
| id | submenu_id | title    | url         | body                                                                             | image_id | hits | votes | grade | publisher_id | time_upload         | last_modified       | published |
+----+------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
|  1 |          1 | ???????? | ssss-d-ssss | <p>&epsilon;&lambda;&lambda;&eta;&nu;&iota;&kappa;?</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>?</p> |        9 |    0 |     0 |   2.5 |            1 | 2013-04-11 10:39:30 | 2013-04-11 11:02:01 |         1 |
+----+------------+----------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+------+-------+-------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I use tinymce for bodyfield..(Tinymce save greek characters very bad)

I also check that in admin page something like the following is missing:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

How can i configure django for utf8 format?
How can i configure tinymce for Emding Greek Chars normally?

**Edit:** changing the collate of the field with mysql commands solve the problem.
Also changing `entity_encoding` from `named` to `raw` in tiny_mce.js solve and the second problem.The only problem now is that the warning doesn't disapear :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `charset` option to `utf8mb4` in the `OPTIONS` dict of the `DATABASES` setting in the Django settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'my_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_pass',
        'HOST': 'my.host',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4'  # This is the relevant line
        }
    }
}
```

These options will be passed as arguments to the mysql driver connection function, which typically is `mysqlclient`. Here you can see in the documentation all these parameters:

https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html#functions-and-attributes

If you use a [different driver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers) for mysql though, you might need a different option.

Also make sure that in the MySQL database, the charset of the either the column, the table or the whole database is set to `utf8mb4`. For more info about character sets in MySQL see:

MySQL docs: [Specifying Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-syntax.html)
MySQL docs: [The utf8mb4 Character Set (4-Byte UTF-8 Unicode Encoding)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)
Stack Overflow: [What is the difference between utf8mb4 and utf8 charsets in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql)

There BTW an ongoing pull-request in Django to make `utf8mb4` the default: https://github.com/django/django/pull/8886

Comment: If you get errors while changing MySQL Collation to utf8mb4, switch the storage engine to InnoDB. In my case it was MyISAM and the collation update failed with error "#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes".

Answer (score 2):

in the Django settings file:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES';",
            'read_default_file': '/platform/auth/mysql.conf',
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

gitaarik's answer above is correct and worked for me after a bit of digging.  I'm adding this for those who use a separate file in the options dict.  Like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'read_default_file': '/platform/auth/mysql.conf',
        'charset': 'utf8mb4',
    },
    'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
}
```

This was my mysql.conf.  It didn't work until I removed the default-character-set option.

```
database = 'xyz_platform'
user = 'xyz'
password = 'xyzpassword'
default-character-set = 'utf8mb4'
```

The correct mysql.conf is this:

```
database = 'xyz_platform'
user = 'xyz'
password = 'xyzpassword'
```